# FilterBy from Start of String

Tags: vue.js

As it currently stands the filterBy filter looks for matching values throughout a string. For instance if I filter by "e", filtered results could entail:
**"Entertainment",
"Internet",
"Services"**.

Is there a way for me to direct filterBy to start matching from the start of the string and ignore the rest so that the only result that comes back from that set is "Entertainment"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own [Filter](https://vuejs.org/guide/custom-filter.html) and check the `indexOf` the field you're searching.

Let's say you have

```
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="search">
  <div v-for="item in items | startsWith search 'name'">
    {{ item.name }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Then your filter can look something like this:

```
Vue.filter('startsWith', function (array, search, field) {
  if (!search.length) return array;

  return array.filter(function(element) {
    return element[field].toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) === 0;
  })
})
```

Here's a quick demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jb22wp1b/

Comment: Much appreciated, it works after adding a check for undefined:

if (search === undefined || !search.length) return array;

Comment: You should be defining search in your data.